Making a boxplot in R using ggplot2
Im trying to make a box and whisker plot in ggplot but I cant seem to make it work.
My data is this below. I can make it just fine using the default boxplot function but not ggplot. The thing is it wants an x and y but I don't have a y axis besides a value.
boxplot(data1) works just fine and its too simple to mess up.


In order to use the boxplot function, you must first pivot longer so your data looks like
library(tidyverse)

# generating random data
data <- tibble(
  before = runif(30, 30, 40),
  after = runif(30, 35, 45)
)

(data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "time", values_to = "value"))
#> # A tibble: 60 × 2
#>    time   value
#>    <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 before  36.0
#>  2 after   36.7
#>  3 before  32.4
#>  4 after   38.7
#>  5 before  33.1
#>  6 after   44.7
#>  7 before  39.0
#>  8 after   36.4
#>  9 before  39.6
#> 10 after   43.8
#> # ℹ 50 more rows

Then, you can use geom_boxplot
ggplot(data) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = time, y = value))


